# Multiple SQL queries in one statement

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to do multiple query in one statement here is my code and it's not working.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE  menu SET DESCRIPTION= ('$txt1'), VISIBLE=('$ckHOME1')
where id='1';
UPDATE  menu SET DESCRIPTION= ('$txt1'), VISIBLE=('$ckHOME1') where id='1';
UPDATE  menu SET DESCRIPTION= ('$txt2'), VISIBLE=('$ckHOME2') where id='2';
UPDATE  menu SET DESCRIPTION= ('$txt3'), VISIBLE=('$ckHOME3') where id='3';
UPDATE  menu SET DESCRIPTION= ('$txt4'), VISIBLE=('$ckHOME4') where id='4';");
$stmt->execute();
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Why are you doing the first update twice?

Comment: And if you're using `mysqli_prepare`, why are you interpolating variables instead of using placeholders?

Comment: I'm wondering wtf the checks `if(!mysqli_query...)` are doing :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also make it as one `UPDATE` statement using `CASE`.

```
UPDATE  menu 
SET     
        DESCRIPTION = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN '$txt1'
                            WHEN id = 2 THEN '$txt2'
                            WHEN id = 3 THEN '$txt3'
                            WHEN id = 4 THEN '$txt4'
                    END,
        VISIBLE = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN '$ckHOME1'
                            WHEN id = 2 THEN '$ckHOME2'
                            WHEN id = 3 THEN '$ckHOME3'
                            WHEN id = 4 THEN '$ckHOME4'
                    END
where   id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) to execute multiple queries in one call.

But there's no need to do multiple queries for what you're doing:

```
UPDATE menu 
SET description = 
        CASE id
            WHEN 1 THEN '$txt1'
            WHEN 2 THEN '$txt2'
            WHEN 3 THEN '$txt3' 
            WHEN 4 THEN '$txt4'
        END,
    visible = 
        CASE id
            WHEN 1 THEN '$ckHOME1'
            WHEN 2 THEN '$ckHOME2'
            WHEN 3 THEN '$ckHOME3' 
            WHEN 4 THEN '$ckHOME4'
        END
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: @user2990463 You call it the same way you call `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Thank you very much Gentlemen, it ROCKS!